# Неправильно выводится счётчик нерабочих дней при использовании momentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Есть такая функция, которая принимает в себя две даты, заводит пустой счётчик и увеличивает его на один если в массиве дат производственного календаря есть такая дата.

```
function countNonWorkingDays(fromDate, toDate) {
  let counter = 0;
  const formatProductionCalendar = productionCalendar.map(element => {
    const d = new Date(element);
    return `${('0' + d.getDate()).slice(-2)}-${('0' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(
      -2,
    )}-${d.getFullYear()}`;
  });
  let currentDate = moment(fromDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
  const finishDate = moment(toDate, 'DD-MM-YYYY');
  while (currentDate <= finishDate) {
    if (formatProductionCalendar.includes(currentDate.format('DD-MM-YYYY'))) {
      counter++;
    }
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(1, 'days');
  }
  return counter;
}
```

Массив дат нерабочих дней в производственном календаре (в самой функции я форматирую productionCalendar под формат 'DD-MM-YYYY' и в итоге получается правильный массив formatProductionCalenar):

```
[
  '2022-01-01',
  '2022-01-02',
  '2022-01-03',
  '2022-01-04',
  '2022-01-05',
  '2022-01-06',
  '2022-01-07',
  '2022-01-08',
  '2022-01-09',
  '2022-01-15',
  '2022-01-16',
  '2022-01-22',
  '2022-01-23',
  '2022-01-29',
  '2022-01-30',
]
```

При запуске подобного теста я ожидаю получить 15 нерабочих дней

```
const fromDate = new Date(2022, 1, 1);
const toDate = new Date(2022, 2, 1);

describe('countNonWorkingDays working correct', () => {
  it('countNonWorkingDays for January', () => {
    expect(countNonWorkingDays(fromDate, toDate)).to.equal(15);
  });
});
```

Но вместо этого счётчик возвращает 10.
Что я делаю неправильно и есть ли варианты упростить такую функцию? А также рассмотреть вариант при котором fromDate > toDate и получать корректную ошибку

Comment: new Date(2022, 0, 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В комментарии [@Konst](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1366756/%d0%9d%d0%b5%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%87%d1%91%d1%82%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-momentjs/1366766#comment2425825_1366756) правильно отметил мою ошибку в самом тесте.

```
const fromDate = new Date(2022, 1, 1);
const toDate = new Date(2022, 2, 1);

describe('countNonWorkingDays working correct', () => {
  it('countNonWorkingDays for January', () => {
    expect(countNonWorkingDays(fromDate, toDate)).to.equal(15);
  });
});
```

Правильно будет вот так:

```
const fromDate = new Date(2022, 0, 1);
const toDate = new Date(2022, 1, 1);

describe('countNonWorkingDays working correct', () => {
  it('countNonWorkingDays for January', () => {
    expect(countNonWorkingDays(fromDate, toDate)).to.equal(15);
  });
});
```